# How to move files from one git branch to another

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a git repository with 2 branches. I want to move all the files of the 2nd branch to the main branch. Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

Comment: Git works with commits. See [merging](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Comment: You need to do a merge into your master branch from feature branch. I think this (video)[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dO9BtPDIHJ8] will help you

Comment: Note that systems do exist where files *are* stored "in" a branch, and you could move them around like this. Git is not such a system, though. In Git, files are stored in commits, and all *existing* commits are frozen for all time. You update a Git repository by adding *new* commits to the repository, where each new commit has whatever you would like it to have. Branch names, in Git, are there to help you (and Git) *find* these commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can‘t move files, but you can **merge** one branch to another. So both branch have the same files.

```
git checkout main
git merge <your 2nd branch>
```